# Cross-Origin Request Blocked error while integrating Paypal

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, asp.net-ajax

While integrating Paypal I am getting below error:

**Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_express-checkout&token=EC-2HF34205DN464620R. (Reason: CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ missing).
Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_express-checkout&token=EC-2HF34205DN464620R. (Reason: CORS request did not succeed).**

Get Request:

```
function notEmpty() {
            $.ajax({
                url: 'https://companionstest.azurewebsites.net/Payment/PaymentWithPayPal',
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'text/html',
                   // 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
                    'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
                    'Access-Control-Allow-Origins': '*',
                   'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials': 'true',
                    'Access-Control-Max-Age': '3600',
                    'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': 'GET',
                    'async': 'true',
                    'crossDomain': 'true',
                    'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': 'Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept',
                    'Accept': 'text/html'
                },

                type: "GET", /* or type:"GET" or type:"PUT" */
                async:"false",
               // dataType: "text/html", 
                success: function (data) {
                    window.location.href = data.redirecturl;
                },
                error: function (httpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {  // detailed error messsage 
                    alert("Error: " + textStatus + " " + errorThrown + " " + httpRequest);
                }
            });
```

}